# Create adjacency matrix from a list of Id and the corresponding club they are part of

Tags: network-programming, stata, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list, peer

The structure of the data in Stata looks something like this:

```
id    club_id
1       1
2       1 
3       2
4       2
5       2
6       3
7       3
8       3
9       3
```

I assume that the network corresponds to the club; hence the adjacency matrix (ordering the data by club) should be block diagonal. I have about 7000 observations.
I am new to Mata. I tried to write many variations of the following code but it won't work:

```
sort id club_id

bys club_id: gen dim = _n     //get the position of the component of the network

mkmat id, mat(id)
mkmat club_id, mat(club_id)
mkmat dim, mat(dim)


local nsubj = _N 

mata:

group_id = st_matrix("id")
AID = st_matrix("club_id")
dim = st_matrix("dim")

adj = J(`nsubj',`nsubj',0)


for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {                   //iteration over each column
    if (club_id[i] == club_id[i+1]) {
        for (k=0, k<= dim[i]-1, k++) {   // the number of columns to be filled
            adj[i, i+k] = 1              // fill the upper part of the matrix
        }
    }

}

end
```

And I thought to reverse the order of dim to fill the lower part of the matrix. I tried many variations of the code and I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Ho risolto il problema: 


sort club_id id


*******************
/* put data in mata*/
mkmat id, mat(id)
mkmat group_id, mat(group_id)

local nsubj = _N 
mata:

group_id = st_matrix("group_id")
id = st_matrix("id")


adj = J(`nsubj',`nsubj',0)


for (i=1; i<=`nsubj'; i++) {                       //iteration over rows
 for (j=1; j<=`nsubj'; j++) {              //iteration over columns
  if (club_id[i] == club_id[j]) {   //for each obs check if the club is the same
   adj[i, j] = 1                     //update the adjacency matrix
  }
 }
}
adj = id,adj   //add id
end

Comment: Sorry, but previous comment is essentially unreadable. Please edit your question. In any case, what does "won't work" mean? For anyone not working with networks, what is the adjacency matrix precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to create an adjacency matrix without Mata. Maybe that can get you started.

```
*Replicate data example
clear
set obs 9
gen id = _n 
expand 9
bysort id: gen club_id = _n

*Generate a variable with a value
gen wins = round(runiform()*10)

*Rename the future variable name
gen club = "club"
egen club_id2 = concat(club club_id )
drop club club_id

*Reshape data
reshape wide wins, i(id) j(club_id2) string
```